# How to emit Maybe.empty in Maybe.create(emitter)?

Tags: java, rx-java2

I want to wrap the following callback code to a Maybe

```
public class FooDataSource 
...
public Maybe<Foo> get(){
    return Maybe.create(emitter -> {
        bar.setCallback(isEmpty -> emitter.onComplete());
    });
}
```

There isn't a call for emitter.onEmpty(), the closest equivalent call I can think of is emitter.onComplete(). I "assume" that onComplete() will become the Maybe.empty() equivalent for Maybe.

The problem is when I test this code

```
FooDataSource.get().subscribe(testObserver);
// Assert that empty returns
testObserver.assertEmpty();
```

I get the it is completed instead of empty.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Completed! (latch = 0, values = 0, errors = 0, completions = 1)
```

How should one emit an onEmpty() downstream?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, [`TestObserver#assertEmpty()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/BaseTestConsumer.html#assertEmpty--) means

> Assert that the TestObserver/TestSubscriber has received a Disposable but no other events.

As I understand, it don't match your case - you invoke `emitter.onComplete()`. To properly test code you can use approach used in [tests of rxjava2 repository](https://www.javatips.net/api/-master/RxJava-2.x/src/test/java/io/reactivex/maybe/MaybeTest.java)

```
@Test
public  void empty() {
    Maybe.empty()
    .test()
    .assertResult();
}
```